# AWS Mobile Hub will not allow me to import an existing API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, aws-mobilehub

So I am trying to integrate AWS lambda into my mobile application, and I have a working API that I created outside of AWS Mobile Hub.  I try to import the API, but it does not update the SDK/Sample app. When I try and create an API through the Mobile Hub, the POST method returns an internal server error, even though I followed the same exact steps in creating this API.  Does anyone know what is going on with this?  It's very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear you are experiencing some issues integrating Lambda with your mobile application. I have a few ideas for root causing this.

First, check the Lambda function can be called by your API by using the test feature in API Gateway. Find it by clicking on the API method in the API Gateway console.

If you see an error here it points to an issue with either (a) bad permissions: the API doesn't have permissions to invoke your Lambda function or (b) your Lambda function can't properly handle the request from your API.

If everything appears OK in the API Gateway console then try testing your API in the Mobile Hub console using the "Test API" button inside the Cloud Logic feature. An error here would indicate an issue with your response mapping or a permissions issue invoking the API outside the API Gateway console.